# Posting on a G+ page

Tags: php, google-apps

Is there a way to post something, using Google Plus API on somebody`s G+ page, on behalf of my Google App? For example Facebook SDK provide such a thing:

```
$page_post = (new FacebookRequest( $session, 'POST', '/{PAGE_ID}/feed', array(
        'access_token' => $access_token,
        'name' => 'Name',
        'link' => 'link',
        'caption' => 'caption',
        'message' => 'message',
    ) ))->execute()->getGraphObject()->asArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Google+ API is read-only, see [here](https://developers.google.com/+/api/):

> Note: The Google+ API currently provides read-only access to public
>   data. All API calls require either an OAuth 2.0 token or an API key.

Comment: Ok but this seems to be applied for users`s profile page, not for a public page. Or, am I missing something?

Comment: @GligorFlorin - I apologize, I'm not that familiar with that API. You should search within the documentation, or, if you can't find your answer there, ask a new question here.